# Laravel echo, socket io fetching in React-Native

Tags: laravel, react-native, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm trying to fetch the model once it was created. The problem, is that the event is getting triggered, but I'm getting nothing in the front-end, so I assume that it is just a front-end problem, so let me show some code:

Lets start with the back-end:

Event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Homework;

class HomeworkCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $homework;

    public function __construct($homework)
    {
        $this->homework = $homework;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('subject.' . $this->homework->subject->id);
    }
}
```

This is how I fire it in my controller:

```
$homework = new Homework([
        'subject_id' => $request->subject_id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id, 
        'title' => $request->name,
        'image' => $path,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'duedate' => $request->date
        ]);

        $homework->save();

        event(new HomeworkCreated($homework));
```

Now, as we can see, it is returning to a channel which in my Laravel echo server is displayed as:

```
Channel: homewrk_database_subject.9 // This confuses me a bit
Event: App\Events\HomeworkCreated
```

When I say "it confuses me", I mean that I really don't know if the route is literally that one, so now we come to my front-end (react-native):

```
render() {

        const echo = new Echo({
            host: 'ws://127.0.0.1:6001',
            broadcaster: 'socket.io',
            client: Socketio,
          });

          echo
            .channel('homewrk_database_subject.', this.props.navigation.getParam('id'))
            .listen('HomeworkCreated', ev => this.homeworks.push(ev)); // trying to add the response to the array.
```

This code is right before the `return`, as this is a class and not functional component.

**My goal is to show add the new model to the array of fetched items to display it**

Comment: use this ``` host: window.location.hostname + ':6001' ``` for your host and the channel name is redis prefix just go to database.php config file and the index of redis -> options -> prefix

Answer (score 1):

The host in your configuration: host: 'ws: //127.0.0.1: 6001', remeber 127.0.0.1 is for the localhost (the self device) then when you use "127.0.0.1" you said connect to your self in the device or emulator where you are running your React Native App, but remember Laraver Echo Server, don't run in your device, it run in the "server" your "pc/mac", then you need use the network ip adress of your computer/mac instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: the host is the Echo parameter like: `new Echo({broadcaster: 'socket.io', host: "ws://192.168.1.100:6001", ... `